# Power BI Display a title and a value on the same line

Tags: powerbi, dax

I want to display some text and a date on the same line but I don't find how to do it.

[image]

As see above I would like to have both "Date to something" and "10/01/2020" on the same line

If you have any idea It would be very helpfull

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this measure

```
Text = "Date to something " & MAX(Calendar[Date])
```

And put the measure in a Card or multi-row card.

Change the MAX()-command to fit your needs.

Also, if you want to force a carriage return you can add a UNICHAR-command, like this:

```
Text = "Date to something " & UNICHAR(10) & MAX(Calendar[Date])
```

N.B
You can ad a lot of cool unichars by using the UNICHAR command to get nice icons etc.

Comment: Thanks and do you know how to change the color of the text "Date to something " ?

Comment: Don't think so, though I'm not sure. I would be verry happy if I'm wrong. I think you have to make different measures for texts with different colours and create separate visuals for them. Then change the font colour in each visual. But if you find a better way, please let me know :)

Comment: Ok, which visual? I have it in a few and they seem to work. I usually only use the included visuals, no imported ones. Also I run a very old version of pbi (due to lag in the IT dep, still running April 2019-version) so maybe this feature has been removed?